# How to wait for a value notifier to be not `null`?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a global `ValueNotifer<MyType?> myNotifier` that initially holds a `null` value.
After some API requests, it will get updated asynchronously and will have a non-null value `MyType`.

I have a method `myMethod` that needs to wait for the `myNotifier` to be initialized before performing some action.

```dart
Future<void> myMethod() async {
  // How to wait for `myNotifier` to have a non-null value here?
  assert(myNotifier.value != null, 'This requires myNotifier.value to be non-null');

  // Perform some action with a non-null `myNotifier.value`.
}
```

How can I wait for `myNotifier.value` to be non-null?

Comment: if the value is async anyway, why not to use `Completer` instead of `ValueNotifier`? all you need is to call `await completer.future` and `completet.complete(...)`

Comment: @pskink The value with change over time, it would be `null, instance0, instance1, instance2` etc. It would be more like a stream than a future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I came up with this solution:

```dart
extension ValueNotifierExtension<T> on ValueNotifier<T?> {
  Future<T> waitForNonNullValue() async {
    if (value != null) return value!;
    final completer = Completer<T>();
    void listener() {
      if (value != null) {
        completer.complete(value);
      }
    }

    addListener(listener);
    final result = await completer.future;
    removeListener(listener);
    return result;
  }
}
```

which allows me to do:

```dart
Future<void> myMethod() async {
  final value = await myNotifier.waitForNonNullValue();
  assert(value != null && myNotifier.value != null, 'This requires myNotifier.value to be non-null');


  // Perform some action with a non-null `myNotifier.value`.
}
```

Comment: Easier to use a Riverpod provider and then you could wait on the provider.future.